# How can I calculate the $\beta$ values such that $Ax=b$ has not solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

*Let be $A$ and $B$, $n \times n$ matrices. And let be a system of equations $Ax=b$.
\begin{align*} A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & 3\\  2 & 1 & 0 & 15\\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\  0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
 \ b=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\  \beta\\  1\\  0 \end{pmatrix} \end{align*}
Find the $\beta$ values such that the system has no solution.*

I calculated $\det(A)=0$ , this means that the system has not a  unique solution. (So the system can have infinite solutions or can have no solution). Also I know that the rank of $A$ is 3. So, how can I determine the $\beta$ values such that this system hasn't solutions?

Comment: Hint: It has no solutions if and on if the rank of the augmented matrix is ${}> \operatorname{rank}(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Just use the gaussian row elimination method to analyze the system of linear equations and for which $\beta$ values have no solution.
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}1&2&0&3&0\\2&1&0&15&\beta\\0&1&1&0&1\\0&0&1&3&0\end{array}\right)\sim\cdots \sim \left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}1&2&0&3&0\\0&-3&0&\color{blue}{9}&\beta\\0&0&1&\color{blue}{3}&\frac{\beta+3}{3}\\0&0&0&0&\color{blue}{\beta+3}\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Yes, You're right! I'm going to correct.